# Ckeditor + ckfinder Как избавиться от противной надписи.

Tags: php, html, javascript, ckeditor

В общем, проблема вот какая: когда подключаешь к ckeditor ckfinder в поле textarea начинает  выводится надпись "Just click the Image or Link button, and then "Browse Server"." - это оочень противно, т.к. если открываешь текст на редактирование - то вместо содержимого, которое должно было загрузиться из БД вылазит эта надпись. Помню как-то читал о способах избавления от нее, но никак не могу найти где была эта информация. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь расскажет как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился очень просто. Ищем у себя в файлах эту строку, сносим. Все работает. Если правильно помню, то она лежит прямо в скрипте подключения визуального редактора к полю текст ариа. Т.е. прямо на странице ввода текста.